# Why can't I launch Jekyll?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
3: from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:18:in `<main>'    
2: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.3_1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:65:in 'gem'   
1: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.3_1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:323:in 'to_spec' 
        /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.3_1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:311:in `to_specs': 
Could not find 'jekyll' (>= 0) among 28 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError) 
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/dayi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648:/Users/dayi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648@global', execute `gem env` for more information
```

Just want to create a blog page in personal GitHub pages in Mac terminal, but it stuck when I text in Jekyll new XX

Comment: Hi Cheung, welcome to StackOverflow. The error message states that Jekyll cannot be found. Did you follow Jekyll's [installation instructions](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/) to install it?

Comment: How did you install `jekyll`?